# How can I fix this ajax error ( data tables warning)?

Tags: ajax, error-handling, datatables, warnings

Http://datatables warning.net/tn/7

When I want to select the course when trying to apply for scholarship. This problem keeps appearing- Data Tables warning: data table-id=ajax error.

And they keep telling me that there is an error from the server side please refresh and try again.

This problem has been disturbing me since yesterday please can you help me fixed this?

Comment: Did you follow the detailed step-by-step troubleshooting and diagnosis instructions provided at [https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/7](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/7)? What were the results of that? "_they keep telling me_" - who is "they"?

Comment: More generally, welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. The way your question is currently written, there is no way anyone will be able to help you.